# Linear algebra problem related to the Kalman filter

Tags: linear-algebra, kalman-filter

I'm studying a special case of the Kalman filter, and the following problem has come up:

Suppose $H \in R^{d\times 1}$, and $R$ is a positive definite $d \times d$ matrix. How would I show that

$H^\top ( H H^\top + R)^{-1} H $ lies between 0 and 1?

Presumably there's an easy fact about matrix norms that I'm missing, but what's the right way to handle this expression?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ever encounters this problem, one can solve it using the [Sherman-Morrison formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).